# AWS Directory Service, can't assign "Domain Admins" to Admin user to correct permissions issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, domainservices

I have AWS Managed Microsoft AD deployed in one region across two availability zones.

In Active Directory Users and Computers, the default `Admin` user was created by AWS and is what I have been using to login and manage the Windows Servers.

When I click on `Member Of`, I see that `Admin` is a member of:

- AWS Delegated Administrators
- Domain Users

The issue is that this user is not a member of `Domain Admin` and I receive some errors. For example, when trying to sign a CSR in `certsrv`, I receive the following message.

> The permissions on the certificate template do not allow the current
> user to enroll for this type of certificate. 0x80094012. Denied by
> Policy Module.

To resolve the issue, when I go to `Admin` in `Active Directory Users and Computers`, click on `Member Of`, click on `Add`, enter `Domain Admins`, and click `Apply`, I receive the following error message.

> You do not have permission to modify the group /Users/Domain Admins.

In summary, the issues are:

- I encounter permission errors when making modifications to certain functions and features
- When I try to add the `Admin` user to `Domain Admins`, I receive a permissions error

How can I solve this?